# How to add multiple placeholders to HTML program?

Tags: html

I have made a program.

```
<div id="todo-app">
    <label class="todo-label" for="new-todo">What do you want to do today?</label>
    <input type="text" id="new-todo" class="todo-input"
        placeholder="buy milk">
</div>
```

But in the `placeholder` section I want it to randomly display other placeholders. For example, if you reload, new placeholder texts will appear. One time it'll say "buy milk" and another "purchase the new iPhone".

Comment: How are you generating the HTML? Are you using a template engine? Which one? Have you tried anything to achieve this so far? What? What happened when you did so?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am making a todo list. This is only a little part of the code. Do you know how to randomly display multiple placeholders (added by me) to generate new results (placeholders) every reload?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far ? and also i dont think u can achive what you are trying to do with just html you need a template engine(example jade) or you need a front end language like angularjs

Comment: Yes. Step 1: randomly choose a placeholder from some collection of placeholders. Step 2: use that one when generating the HTML. The precise implementation will depend on a number of things you haven't bothered to tell us, so that's as specific as anyone can be. For a start, **what language are you using?!**

Comment: @MikyasTADESSE I have a proper running code, no issues. I just want to add a feature. Which would be allowing multiple placeholders so a different one will appear each reload.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying to allow multiple placeholders. I know how to add a single one. Is there some sort of random selection feature? Would it be: placeholder="buy milk", "purchase phone"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe HTML?

Comment: In HTML? No. You would need to do this client-side with JS or server-side in whatever you're using to generate the HTML to begin with. **HTML is not a programming language**. What are you using to *serve* the HTML? How do people view your app?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want you to visit this site, its where my program is: todo360@weebly.com

Comment: You're making no sense, this seems fruitless. The site you want me to visit is an email address and you appear to not understand the very basics of what you're doing. Best of luck.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oops my mistake it is todo360.weebly.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you refresh the page the value of the textbox will be different

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
  var items = Array("buy milk","purchase the new iPhone","test","hello");
  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
  document.getElementById("newtodo").value=item;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
<a id="result"></a>
<div id="todo-app">
    <label class="todo-label" for="new-todo">What do you want to do today?</label>
    <input type="text" id="newtodo" class="todo-input">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can never be done using HTML only.

you need to make this with a programming language from the server side, OR by using JavaScript code `getElementsByName()`.

So, for example, for your:

```
<input type="text" id="new-todo" class="todo-input" name="todo" placeholder="buy milk">
```

the code will be:

```
document.getElementsByName('todo')[0].placeholder='purchase the new iPhone';
```

Comment: No I have already completed the code. What I want is for every time I load the site a new placeholder appears.